# Idea for a PC bios beep buzzer

Tags: speakers, piezo-buzzer, motherboard, lm386, pc

Hi I want to make a buzzer for my PC motherboard. Similar things like this:

https://boip.in/home/rajiekart-pc-motherboard-internal-speaker-bios-alarm-buzzer-1-pcs-pack?gclid=CjwKCAjwnK36BRBVEiwAsMT8WNyz6K-LtLk4YecyH2NH6YHbLz0rWyYm8Za_3LTn4GwUSZPk7ViyzhoCFXEQAvD_BwE

My plan is to use a normal speaker with a amplifier like LM386. Is it possible to connect LM386 inputs to PC motherboard buzzer output pin ?

Comment: How loud do you need it. Piezo de les resistance is betta ;). Which MOBO?

Comment: It's possible, sure, but linear amplifier is wasted on a digital source.  If you really want to do it, use a coupling capacitor.  But why not just use a transistor?

Comment: You should be able to directly connect an 8 ohm speaker to it. Then you can decide if the poor quality of the sound justifies amplification.

Answer (score 1):

Motherboard speaker connections allow directly use of 8 ohm speaker. That's how they were originally designed in the 80's and they still are compatible.

There is no need for an amplifier, and in fact the motherboard speaker output pin is usually open-collector output so direct connection to amplifier input would most likely not work, it requires at least some biasing network to convert the open-collector output to voltage output.